# Fetching Mail Id in Login with Facebook?

Tags: javascript, c#

How can i fetch mail id in login with facebook option.I created a sample project and i can fetch username,but i cant fetch mail ID.

My coding is following.

I created an App ID and i implement it in following code.

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '###############',
            cookie: true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
            // the session
            xfbml: true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version: 'v2.5' // use version 2.2
        });


        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });

    };



 function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);


        if (response.status === 'connected') {

            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
              'into this app.';
        } else {

            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
              'into Facebook.';
        }
    }


  function testAPI() {
        var id, eid, Username;
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function (response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
              'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!' + response.id + ' ' + response.phoneno + ' ' + response.country;
            Username = response.name;
            eid = response.email;
            id = response.id;

        });


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'LoginWithFB.aspx/fbacctdeta',
            data: "{Username:'" + Username + "',eid:'" + eid + "',id:'" + id + "'}",
            async: true,
            success: function () {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I think it's waste of time posting questions in this.No use.If my question is not understanding then tell that.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch  the mail Id and other information only after Facebook completes the app review of your app at developer option of [Facebook for Developers](http://developers.facebook.com)

for getting the client info

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic info=fb.Get("\me");
```

Comment: Sorry i cant understand? I check that,but there is no option for fetching mail ID

Comment: it in cludes first name, last name ,email address,location,image url etc. of the current user.Now you can use this e-mail or name to verify your user or register new user etc.

Comment: you can take the email Id only if your app is verified